Steam does not open in Ubuntu 23.10 Raspberry Pi
I try to open Steam from the launcher on my fresh Ubuntu install on my Pi and it shows
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:arm64 libc6:i386 libegl1:arm64 libgbm1:arm64 libgl1-mesa-dri:arm64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:arm64 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-amd64:amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386

Press return to proceed with the installation: 
..............................................................E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/mantic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/mantic-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/mantic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libnss-nisplus libnss-nis libcrypt1 libc6-dev

Package libgl1:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgl1-amber-dri

E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1:i386' has no installation candidate

Press return to continue: 

I HAVE tried all of the solutions seen before. Thanks in advance.

RP has a different architecture - ARM64, but Steam needs i386 packages, which aren't available for RP. What made you think Steam could be installed on an RP in the first place?

@mikewhatever I didn't know rpi was ARM64 lol.

The RPI is Arm64, Steam cannot be installed on it.
